# Pdfbookmark with number

Tags: pdf, bookmarks

I'm importing some pdf files, to my document.

```
\pdfbookmark{First}{r01}

\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{inc/r01.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{Second}{r02}
\includepdf[pages=-,pagecommand={}]{inc/r02.pdf}
```

These are book chapters, with their own formatting - it's a reason, why I can't use `\section` there.

I don't want to have any table of contents in my document, just the chapters names in the bookmarks area together with the numbering. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`hyperref` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), your code should work to produce the bookmarks. Alternatively, the smaller [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark) provides the same interface for *just* PDF bookmarks. Remember that you need to compile your document at least twice in order for the PDF bookmarks to be accurate.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\usepackage{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
%\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\begin{document}
% file.pdf contains 8 pages of \lipsum[1-40] in article document class
\pdfbookmark{1 First}{r01}
\includepdf[pages=1-2]{file.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{2 Second}{r02}
\includepdf[pages=3-4]{file.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{3 Third}{r03}
\includepdf[pages=5-6]{file.pdf}

\pdfbookmark{4 Fourth}{r04}
\includepdf[pages=7-8]{file.pdf}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding bookmarks to the document works fine, but this is not the question. The question is, how to _automatically_ number the bookmarks, as opposed to your example, where you put the numbers by hand.

Comment: Do you have access to the `.aux` file that produced `r0?.pdf`? Even more desirable, do you have access to the LaTeX code that produced `r0?.pdf`?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. r0?.pdfs were exported from MS Word.

Comment: Well, unfortunately you'll need some way to process the source in order to extract this information. Word documents are binary and LaTeX would not be able to extract the contents nor know which components represent a chapter or just plain text. You could convert the source from Word to (La)TeX using [Word2TeX](http://word2tex.com/). Of course, this heavily depends on the contents of the Word for it to be effective.

Comment: I don't care about sections etc inside imported pdfs, I just put them as they are and add bookmarks to have a quick access to them. Therefore, includepdf + pdfbookmarks are quite enough - except the fact, that they don't automatically add bookmarks numbers. Will I have to type the numbers by hand? I wish there is more elegant solution.

Comment: As mentioned already, this is not possible due to the binary format of a Word document. You would be required to manually add the chapter information. Alternatively, saving the Word document (or PDF) as a text version, stripping out everything except the chapters and then reading this from within LaTeX *might* be an option. However, the labour involved to do this far outweighs a manual insertion of chapter numbers, don't you think? How many chapters are there? How often do you perform this operation? Consider those and make the decision.